# Ayin Hara indifference

Tags: ayin-hara-evil-eye

If someone does not care about it, does Ayin Hara affect him?

Comment: Harav Musafi writes: ש עין הרע, אך אין לחשוב על זה, ומי שעוסק בתורה לא צריך לחשוש ממנה.

Comment: If it didn't affect people who didn't care about it, why would anyone care?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reb Moshe** in the **Iggras Moshe** (אה''ע חלק ג' סימן כ''ו) says **NO**.
Even though the Gemara (פסחים ק''י ע''ב) says the Heter by Zugos (eating or drinking paired items) nonetheless Reb Moshe says the same applies to Ayin Hara.

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbe also extends the Gemara to Ayin Hara in general, see here: http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/eternal-joy-2/05.htm#t31

Answer (score 6):

It would seem the Mishnah Berurah disagrees with [Reb Moshe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/ayin-hara-indifference/1932#1932). In Hilchos Kriyas Hatorah (Orach Hachaim 141:6) it is brought that two brothers should not be called up one after the other, and he says that that's even if they are not Makpid. This seems to indicate he thinks Ayin Hara does affect those who do not care.

Comment: But see Alex's answer citing the Aruch Hashulchan

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting that the Aruch Hashulchan with piskei Mishnah Berurah does not note the Mishnah Berurah's disagreement in this case.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to the ayin hara of two brothers or a father and son getting aliyos one after the other, the Aruch Hashulchan (O.C. 141:8) states:

> ומאן דלא קפיד יכול לעשות כמו שירצה
>
> One who is not particular about [ayin hara] can do as he wants.