# Dedicating a Mitzva to unborn child

Tags: mitzvah, pregnancy-birth, ayin-hara-evil-eye

Can a Mitzva be done on behalf of an child still in the womb?
I.e can I do a donation to a charity in my name, my wife's and my soon to be +1?
If so, in what name would that mitzva be done in as +1 doesnt have a name or even a gender yet.
My Wife is currently in her 2nd trimester.

Would one be inviting an ayin-hara by doing this?

Comment: Worth considering: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1931/5

Comment: This isn't something i'd do (we are due in a week, G-d-willing), but i don't know if we poskin from the ayin hara.  (PS, your fetus definitely has a sex by now, you just don't know it and b'sha'ah tovah)

Comment: b'shah tovah to you too! thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *do a Mitzva* for other people, the same way you cannot breathe, eat or go on diet for other people.

Why? Because a Mitzva generates a spiritual reward that you will enjoy in the world to come.

If you cause other people to do a Mitzva, you get brownie points for that too. Since your children are in existence because of you, you get some credit for their Mitzvot.

What you can do is to pray for other people. The Gemara in Brachot (60a) mentions that you can pray for the health of an unborn baby.

When you give charity, you just became more righteous - in a tiny way - and your prayers are therefore slightly more likely to be answered.

Comment: "in a tiny way" ???

Comment: @Ypnypn - yes, in a tiny, miniscule way. It's a very long way "to the top" and every good deed is a tiny step. (I know it's popular to call every do-gooder a "Tzadik", as he's moving in the right direction, but that's a huge exaggeration. It takes years of work to get anywhere near the top.)